# Remove dynamically added record (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a set of records that get displayed from a database:

```
<tr>
  <td>Full Name</td>
  <td><a class="remove-user" href="/remove-user/6/">remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

I can remove them (non-dynamically) and show a confirm dialog before doing so:

```
$('a.remove-user').on('click', function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this user?");
});
```

But, when I add a dynamic row via ajax - I can't make the confirm dialog to show afterwards:

```
$('#user_add_final').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: "/ajax/user/",
          type: "post",
          data: values,
          success: function(response){
               json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
               $('.users tr:last').after("<tr><td>"+json.user.fullname+"</td><td><a class=\"remove-user\" href=\"/action/remove-user/"+json.user.userid+"/\">remove</a></td></tr>");
          },
          error:function(){
              alert(failure);
          }   
    }); 
});
```

Can someone help me getting this to work?

Comment: Your new code should at least *try* to call `confirm`, should it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't bound to the click events of records added after the fact.  Take a look at your handler:

```
$('a.remove-user').on('click', function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this user?");
});
```

The part which identifies the elements:

```
$('a.remove-user').on(...
```

executes *once*, when the page loads.  So it can only identify matching elements which exist *when the page loads*.  Handlers are attached to elements, not selectors.  So any elements which don't exist when the page loads aren't going to be identified by this code.

However, you can use an overload of `.on()` to attach the handler to a common unchanging *parent* element and filter from child elements.  It would look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.remove-user', function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this user?");
});
```

This actually attaches the handler to `document` (which doesn't change via AJAX) and runs for any click anywhere in the document, but filters on the second selector each time to only respond to elements which match *that* selector.  That way elements added later in the life of the document are still captured.

You don't need to use `document`, any common parent element will work.  The table, a containing `div`, etc.

I've written more about this [here](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
$('table').on('click', 'a.remove-user', function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this user?");
});
```

Ussing event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate your event, as the newly added row wasn't present at the time the script was loaded.

```
$('.users').on('click', 'a.remove-user', function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this user?");
});
```